# Virtual Connect Manager UI is broken for HP C7000

Tags: hp, blade-server

My business is using an HP C7000 enclosure. We had an ethernet mezzanine module fail last week which caused our entire production network to go down. Through the process of attempting to resolve this issue I ran into some issues with Virtual Connect Manager. After replacing the failed mezzanine module I logged into the VCM. The first problem that I ran into was the "Loading Libraries 4%" issue. Which I resolved with the following post:

https://community.hpe.com/t5/HPE-BladeSystem-Virtual-Connect/loading-libraries-on-virtual-connect-manager/td-p/6744910

However after resolving the 'loading libraries' issue the VCM is broken. When I click on various configuration settings within VCM the WebUI returns blank white space within the framework of the web interface.. There is also no drop down menu along the left hand side of the UI.

I have been tasked with getting this C7000 enclosure working again until we can allocate budget to our Co-Location for new hardware. Has anyone seen this problem before? Or have any recommendations to get VCM's WebUI functioning again?

Outside of the VCM WebUI I do have CLI access to VCM for this enclosure however the CLI is not very intuitive. Ultimately what I need to do is get this new (identical) ethernet mezzanine module functioning again. If I must use the CLI at this point what commands would I run to configure the new mezzanine card? I can review the configuration settings of the enclosure within Onboard Administrator. I just can't make changes within VCM.
Can someone please help me with this situation?

Thanks!